# Run a command multiple times, but load it just once

Tags: linux

For testing reasons I need to run the Citrix command `wfica` multiple times. Each time it will open a session with a different Citrix test user and perform some actions.

Now my workstation got into memory troubles at the 98th session :) I need to get it up to 150 sessions. The problem is not so much the Citrix session, that uses about 70KiB. It is `wfica`. That uses 15MiB.

Is it possible that Linux will use the `wfica` that is already loaded in to memory, instead of loading a new one every time?

Comment: Most likely not, as that compromises security and cross thread stability. What you need to ask.. Can i Load wfica once.. with 150 sessions maintained within it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry nope.  Badly written programs are badly written.  If the memory management isn't done properly, you're just going to be out of luck.  For a Citrix server... if you only have ~1.5gb of RAM to play with... you really have an under-powered server for the task.  I'm surprised you managed to get ~90 users on that machine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's not a server but my workstation. The server has 60GiG's. I want to know how many session it can handle with 'default' user behaviour. So I write some scripts and launched the sessions from my workstation. The server didn't had any problems, my workstation did when it ran out of memory and swap space...